# You can't find an equation for the cross-sectional shape when given only the formula for volume

Tags: calculus

Why not?

[image]

I'm trying to design a calculus I problem. I want them to eventually prove that the volume of a cone (oblique or even with irregular base) is $\frac{\pi r^2 h}{3}$, I also want them to know what a cone is (and what it isn't) -- so I thought this might be a good starting question. But, I don't know if it goes where I want it to.

---

Update: Making this more clear... I should have said more!

Imagine each "nose cone" has its vertex at the origin and the perpendicular (from the vertex to the base) is the x-axis. If you have a formula A(x) for the cross-sectional area of the "nose cone" at x, perpendicular to the x-axis then the volume is $\int_0^h A(x)dx$.

So, here we have formulas for the volumes of a few solids from NASA. (Only one is a cone.) Can we recover $A(x)$ from these? No, we can't! Not without assuming that the cones are not oblique or otherwise irregular.

(I'll take this as a sign that this would confuse my students!)

Comment: @a little don: I'm sorry, I don't quite understand the question!

Answer (score 1):

The cross-sectional area is simply the derivative of the volume with respect to h, 
by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.  For a problem, how about a cone whose base is a cardioid?

Comment: You mean with respect to x, right? h is a constant.

Comment: @a little don: what is $x$?

Comment: The active variable in the integral used to find the volume. It doesn't appear in the final equation... that's the whole point.

Comment: @a little don: $V'=A$, no matter if you write it as $V'(x)=A(x)$ or $V'(h)=A(h)$...

Comment: @Hans Yes. And we still don't know what the shape of the base.

Comment: a little don, it is not possible to determine the shape of the base, only its area.

Comment: I'm going to delete this and consider posting it later after rewording it.

Comment: I was thinking that "having an equation for the cross-sectional area" was the knowing the shape of the cross-section.